# Software for creating GPS route from database of routes

Tags: gps, mapping, gpx

Let's say I have access to a database of trails cris-crossing a forest. Is there any software I can load these routes into and somehow select some of them and export it into a route (so that I can follow this route with a GPS device)?

So the main problem is somehow selecting a subset of the routes by point and click and then exporting it.

There are apps like Garmin Connect and Strava which will let you create routes, but they are very road-based, and do not have the routes I have access to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [Google distance matrix api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview) with travel mode set to [walking/bicycling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview#travel_modes)